# How to estimate $\sum_{q \leq Q, n \in \mathbb{Z}} w(n/q)$ with $w$ a smooth function?

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, asymptotics

Let $w$ be a smooth function with compact support. I am interesting in estmating $\sum_{q \leq Q, n \in \mathbb{Z}} w(n/q)$ as $Q \to \infty$. By applying the Poisson summation formula we can deduce
$$
\sum_{q \leq Q, n \in \mathbb{Z}} w(n/q) = \frac12 \hat{w}(0) + O(Q).
$$
I was wondering is it possible to obtain a secondary term for a very nice of choice of $w$?
Any comments are appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sum_n w(x+n)=\sum_k \hat{w}(k) e^{2i\pi kx}$$ then $$\sum_{q=1}^Q \sum_n w(n/q)=\sum_{q=1}^Q \sum_{m=0}^{q-1}\sum_k \hat{w}(k) e^{2i\pi k m/q}=\sum_{q=1}^Q \sum_k \hat{w}(k)  \sum_{m=0}^{q-1} e^{2i\pi k m/q}$$

$$= \sum_{q=1}^Q \sum_{k, q|k} \hat{w}(k) q= \frac{Q(Q+1)}{2}\hat{w}(0)+\sum_{k\ne 0} \hat{w}(k) \sum_{q| k,q\le Q}q$$
$$ = \frac{Q(Q+1)}{2}\hat{w}(0)+\sum_{k\ne 0} \hat{w}(k) \sigma_1(k)+O(\sum_{|k|\ge Q} |\hat{w}(k)| \sigma_1(k))$$
Since $\hat{w}$ is rapidly decreasing, for any fixed $r>1$ it is
$$ = \frac{Q(Q+1)}{2}\hat{w}(0)+\sum_{k\ne 0} \hat{w}(k) \sigma_1(k)+O(\sum_{|k|\ge Q} k^{-r})$$ $$=\frac{Q(Q+1)}{2}\hat{w}(0)+\sum_{k\ne 0} \hat{w}(k) \sigma_1(k)+O(Q^{1-r})$$